# subprocess spawned from Celery task never terminates and proc.poll() == None status stays all the time

Tags: python, subprocess, celery

I notice this issue so I wrote the following simple demonstration code and the issue still exists.

I have a worker.py that emulates some longtime process and report current progress via stdout

```
from sys import stdout
import time


def main():

    to_print = ("Start\n").encode("utf-8")
    stdout.buffer.write(to_print)
    stdout.flush()

    for i in range(0, 11):
        time.sleep(1)
        to_print = ("progress:%d\n" % (i*10)).encode("utf-8")
        stdout.buffer.write(to_print)
        stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I register a celery task. In the task, I use subprocess to call worker.py

```
@celery.task(name="tasks.runner", bind=True)
def run_task(self):

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "worker.py"], bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    run_task_pid = os.getpid()
    update_progress(self, proc, run_task_pid)
    print("I am at the last line of run_task")

def update_progress(self, proc, run_task_pid):
    while True:
        print('in the loop')
        line = proc.stdout.readline()

   # I first notice the problem from here, I found it never breaks 
   # proc.poll() is always None suggesting proc never be terminated

        if line == "" and proc.poll() is not None:
            break

        linestr = line.decode("utf-8")

        if "progress:" in linestr:
            progress = int(linestr.strip().split(":")[-1])
            self.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={"progress": progress,
                                                      "subprocess_pid": proc.pid,
                                                      "run_task_pid": run_task_pid,
                                                      "description": ""})
    # I use this line to break because proc.poll() not work here
            if progress == 100:
                self.update_state(state="SUCCESS", meta={ "progress": progress,
                                                          "subprocess_pid": proc.pid,
                                                          "run_task_pid": run_task_pid,
                                                          "description": ""})
                break

        time.sleep(0.5)
```

I start celery task by flask, just a simple plain callback, and I have a small webservice to tell me process ids. Anyway, celery task starts to run like this

```
def worker():
    task = send_task('tasks.runner')
```

When celery task already finished, from the confirmation is looks quite good, the last line of code in run_task is executed and task itself "succeeded" as Celery tells me:

```
$ I am at the last line of run_task
$ Task tasks.runner[0a0ff60c-ab09-4279-91f8-f9dd5010a49c] succeeded in 11.078552599996328s: None
```

But if I looked at ps, the subprocess.pid is still there with command as (python), this explains why proc.poll() always suggests subprocess is still running ...

```
PID TTY           TIME CMD
5160 ttys002    0:00.00 (python)
```

This looks like a zombie process but taking no resource. This is very annoying, because even this is a fake zombie, the subprocess proc has no clean exit signal (in the code, I have to explicitly say we can break when progress==100, otherwise as you can tell celery work actually will run forever because it never breaks). And also I am not sure if there is any other issue because subprocess does not really terminate.

I wonder whether anybody knows this issue? Is it some known problem for Celery working with subprocess because it creates some strange child process dependency? I find I almost have no way to kill it manually, the only way is I stop Celery itself. Did I do something wrong? Thank you for your help

Comment: Eventually the problem has been fixed. The problem comes from if line == "" , somehow by the end, subprocess returns an empty bytes "", namely b"", in python 3 bytes != str, therefore although proc.poll() returns none it will not break anyway. Therefore it goes forever. On the other hand, in order to break I add another breakpoint if progress==100. This makes the code exit, however, the master process never gets the return code. So the pid never terminates because OS will not handle a process that has not yet handled by master process